# Localhost unable to connect node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just recently installed node. I followed its getting started guide and run the file. Here is the file :

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(3000, "localhost", () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${localhost}:${3000}/`);
});
```

After I run localhost:3000 on firefox it says unable to connect.

Comment: On the line `console.log(\`Server running at http://${localhost}:${3000}/\`);`, `localhost` is undefined. Testing locally, I replaced that with the `hostname` variable you defined earlier, and it worked.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend reusing those `hostname` and `port` variables you defined instead of hardcoding `3000` and `"localhost"` in the server.listen call, just to clean up the code a bit.

Comment: I can see the "guide" you tried to follow - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/ - just seems you can't even copy/paste properly!

Comment: when you created that file in the question, how did you attempt to "run" it?